# Custom command not enabled

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to implement a custom command for a right-click menu item to allow the application to reinitialize a specific state. Following Heinzi's guidance in [How do I add a custom routed command in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601393/how-do-i-add-a-custom-routed-command-in-wpf), I've added the necessary XAML/bindings.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <RoutedUICommand x:Key="UnsetCommand" Text="Reset" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
  <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource UnsetCommand}" Executed="UnsetExecuted" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>

<ContextMenu>
  <MenuItem Command="{StaticResource UnsetCommand}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

And behind code

```
private void UnsetExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  FreeResources();

  Unset(false);
}
```

The issue I'm having is the menu item isn't enabled as expected.

[image: Reset menu item isn't enabled]

Thoughts on what I'm missing here?

EDIT: Fixed typo UnsetsCommand -> UnsetCommand

Comment: What does your implementation of `UnsetCommand` look like?

Comment: @Rachel It's the MenuItem visual tree thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this WPF RoutedCommand bound Context MenuItem disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455551/why-is-this-wpf-routedcommand-bound-context-menuitem-disabled). The accepted answer there (put your command bindings in `ContextMenu.CommandBindings`) works, but there's another answer [which suggests binding `MenuItem.CommandTarget` to `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7381736/424129) -- and that solution works also. WPF MenuItems are out of the visual tree, which creates endless problems when it comes to binding.

Comment: I think it may just be a typo UnsetsCommand see the 's' at the end of Unset

Comment: @kenny The typo must have crept in when OP wrote the question, or else the text "Reset" wouldn't be appearing in the screenshot of the menu item.

Comment: @EdPlunkett good point.

Comment: Yes. It's a typo. Thanks for catching it. I haven't yet had a chance to get back to experiment with this solution, but it's probably the correction I needed.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks for the answer. I decided to go with the CommandTarget version.